# what is the result for the following Integral?

Tags: integration, absolute-value

I would like to find the result for the following integral
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty x e^{-|x|/a}\cdot e^{-|x-y|/b} \, dx
$$

where $a$ and $b$ are constants. $x$ and $y$ are variables

Comment: Suppose for the moment that $y>0$. Then $$ \frac{|x|} a + \frac{|x-y|} b = \begin{cases} \dfrac x a + \dfrac {x-y} b & \text{if } x\ge y, \\ \\ \dfrac x a + \dfrac {y-x} b & \text{if } 0\le x\le y, \\  \\ \dfrac {-x} a + \dfrac{y-x} b & \text{if }  x\le 0. \end{cases} $$ If $y<0$ one can do a similar thing; only details are different. $\qquad$

Comment: Thank you.
please can you just find the result for one case

Comment: Related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1808236/i-need-to-find-the-following-integral?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Hint: break it up into cases depending on the signs of $x$ and $x-y$.